# Restricting list iteration in EJS to first 50 records

Tags: javascript, ejs, canjs

I am passing a list from Canjs javascript to an EJS template. This list can have more than 500 records but I want to restrict the iteration to display the first 50 records only, so how could I restrict the iteration to 50. Any ideas???

**EJS template:**

```
<ul>
  <% list(items, function(item){ %>
  <div class="text-center">
  <span class="name"><%= item.attr('firstname') %>,<%= item.attr('lastname') %>
  </span>      
  <span class="description"><%= item.attr('description') %></span>
  </div>
  <% }) %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `items.slice(0, 50)` in place of `items`.

Answer (score 1):

in alternative you can use :

```
<% 
var limit = 50;
$.each(items, function(index, item){ 
    if(index <= limit) {    
%>
<li>
<div class="text-center">
<span class="name"><%= item.attr('firstname') %>,<%= item.attr('lastname') %>
</span>      
<span class="description"><%= item.attr('description') %></span>
</div>

 <%} })%>
</li>
</ul>
```